# JInternalFrameFixture.comboBox() in AssertJ Swing 3.2

Tags: java, swing, assertj

I'm migrating some code from FEST Swing 1.2.1 to AssertJ Swing 3.2. In the old code there are calls to

- `JInternalFrameFixture.comboBox()`
- `JInternalFrameFixture.label()`
- `JInternalFrameFixture.slider()`

Unfortunately I do not see any matching method in [`JInternalFrameFixture` of AssertJ Swing](https://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/swing/api/org/assertj/swing/fixture/JInternalFrameFixture.html).
What should I use instead of the methods above in AssertJ Swing 3.2?

I've found that [`ComponentContainerFixture`](https://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/swing/api/org/assertj/swing/fixture/ComponentContainerFixture.html) has a `comboBox()` method but `JInternalFrameFixture` does not implement this one in AssertJ Swing.

Comment: Can't you simply create a new JComboBoxFixture directly? After all, the method only seems to return a new instance of that in FEST Swing 1.2.1 as far as I can see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In AssertJ 3.2, given [access to AssertJ's `Robot`](https://github.com/joel-costigliola/assertj-swing/blob/assertj-swing-parent-pom-3.2.0/assertj-swing/src/main/java/org/assertj/swing/testing/AssertJSwingTestCaseTemplate.java#L46-L51), and an already existing `JInternalFrameFixture`, you can find a combo box within an internal frame with the following snippet:

```
robot().finder().findByType(internalFrameFixture.target(), JComboBox.class);
```

Additonally, I have submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/joel-costigliola/assertj-swing/pull/189) to `assertj-swing` to allow the fluent style that you are describing, i.e., `frame.internalFrame().comboBox()`.  Hopefully it will be incorporated into a future version of AssertJ Swing.